# Suppose $G$ is a group, with a subgroup $K$ and a normal subgroup $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $h, h_1 \in H$ and $k, k_1 \in K$.  If $hk = h_1k_1$, show that $h_1=hb$ and $k_1=b^{-1}k$, for some $b \in H \cap K$.

I noticed that $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of $K$, and $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$. Then, I do not know what to do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $H$ is a normal subgroup of what group? $G$?

Comment: "$b$ is a normal subgroup of $k$"? these two are elements, not subgroups.

Comment: @Nameless I meant H ∩ K is a subgroup of K

Comment: @Krish Thank you for pointing it out. I meant to say that  H ∩ K is a subgroup of K

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

$hk = h_1k_1 \Rightarrow h^{-1}h_1 = kk_1^{-1} \in H \cap K$(why?). Choose $b = h^{-1}h_1 = kk_1^{-1}.$ Then $hb = hh^{-1}h_1 = h_1$ and $b^{-1}k = k_1k^{-1}k = k_1.$